# Safe to hardwire DC adapter bypassing original socket on Gateway MX3231

Tags: laptop-repair

I have found plenty of places where I can procure a replacement DC jack for my model of laptop. what I'm  wondering is if it would be terribly dangerous to avoid the jack all together and just hardwire the DC adapter into the PCB the jack was initially soldered to. It's a long abandoned computer and I mostly just wanted to use it as a media server, so its portability is no longer important.

Comment: *"into the slot the jack was in"*  -- Your improper use of terminology doesn't make sense.  Direct connection of a power cable to PCB requires somekind of strain relief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would it be terribly dangerous?

Potentialy, yes. So proceeding is done at your own risk and depends on your soldering skills, what wire goes where and solution on how to keep the cord from being pulled from the soldered area by accident.

If you are adventurous and are going to do it anyway, sawdust mentioned strain releif. This would be something that would hold the cord firmly to the lap top case to help secure it in place. Some examples would be:

[image: strain relief]

[image: Strain releif 2]